# I need something like a DataTable in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have looked around but cannot seem to find anything quite like i need.

I need to read in a CSV file with column headers eg:

```
NAME;AGE;HEIGHT
dan;36;180
john;31;181
ben;30;190
```

what object can i parse it into read where i can then reference it like so:

```
object.name = (string) someSortOfDataStructure["NAME"];
object.name = (int) someSortOfDataStructure["AGE"];
```

or

```
object.name = someSortOfDataStructure.getColumn("NAME");
```

In C# I can do this with something like a DataTable / DataRow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think OOP. You need to create a `Person` class with the properties `name`, `age` and `height`.

```
public class Person {

  private String name;
  private String age;
  private String height;

  // Getter and setter methods...
}
```

Next, read CSV file line by line using a `BufferedReader`. For each line you want to split the line using `line.split(";");` to give you an `String[]` containing the tokens.

For the line you can now create a `Person` from the tokens;

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName(tokens[0]);
person.setAge(tokens[1]);
person.setHeight(tokens[2]);
```

Note that this **assumes** the positions of the columns. If you want to remove this assumption you need to `Map` the header to a position.

```
String headerLine = "NAME;AGE;HEIGHT";
String[] headers = headerLine.split(";");
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
  map.put(headers[i], i);
}
```

You can then get the position of a column by it's name;

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName(tokens[map.get("NAME")]);
person.setAge(tokens[map.get("AGE")]);
person.setHeight(tokens[map.get("HEIGHT")]);
```

`Table` type classes are an anti-pattern. They tend to appear when the programmer can't be bothered to think in terms of Objects. I often see `Table` classes in legacy java applications and its a real PITA to work with them. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks it was the hasmap part that helped me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... you can use default table model. It is made to support swing tables, I am not sure if it will be able to help you or not.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html

Comment: Yup, I changed(edited) my answer after looking into c# datatable

Comment: Do you find this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) has a [`Table`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) interface which should be what you need.